# How do I grow clovers

Tags: houseplants, propagation, clover

So in my yard, I have a patch of clovers (standard white clovers) that give a lot of four leaves and a few five leaves. is there any way for me to grow them inside and mutate them to always be four leaves or higher? I want to press and sell them but it could always be faster. I'm not really all that good at growing plants so if possible a step by step guide would be amazing.

Comment: Clover **as a houseplant** - good luck with that, you'll need it, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to force an outdoor plant into being a houseplant (not always the easiest thing to do), you might want to consider a tropical-ish plant that can be grown as a houseplant: plants in the genus *Oxalis*.

Lucky Clover (*Oxalis tetraphylla*, also found as *Oxalis deppei*) could work for you, if you don't mind that the leaves have a bit of reddish-purple on them. The leaves *are*, however, reliably "four-leaved", so no mutations needed. These would definitely be easier to grow in the ground if you live in US Zone 7 and warmer, but can do well indoors if treated properly.

This [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxalis_tetraphylla) gives more details, as well as cultural information. The key points are that the plants need at least partial direct sun when indoors and free-draining potting soil. Adding a little coconut coir and/or perlite to commercial soil would be a good idea. You should use a timed-release fertilizer like Osmocote (US) three times a year. During the winter, keep the plant away from your home's heat source (radiator, heating duct).

More cultural information is [here](https://www.gardendesign.com/plants/oxalis.html).

Comment: hey thanks i'll just try to take care of the patch as best as possible.